# ng-init and ng-options html str issue angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-options, angularjs-ng-init

I have to dynamically create a select list in angularjs directive. I have double quote ng-init and ng-options, using angular.element to create the element and append to a div with id **preview**. the code looks like followings

```
$('button').click(function() {
     var ng_select_str = '<div class="col-sm-8" ng-init="options=[1,2,3]">' +
                             '<select class="form-control" id="inventory-qq" ng-model="inventory.qq" ng-options="opt as opt for opt in options"></select>' +
                         '</div>';

     var element = angular.element(ng_select_str);
     $('#preview').append(element);
});
```

however the select list render without any options value(empty select list). I wonder how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to have directive for such logics where you can generate and compile dynamic contents.

See simple example below, but it needs some more work

```js
var module = angular.module('testApp', [])
  .directive('test', function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      template: '<button ng-click="appendSelectBox()">add select box</button>',
      controller: function($scope, $element) {
        $scope.appendSelectBox = function() {
          var el = $compile('<div class="col-sm-8" ng-init="options=[1,2,3]"><select class="form-control" id="inventory-qq" ng-model="inventory.qq" ng-options="opt as opt for opt in options"></select></div>')($scope);
          $element.parent().append(el);
        };
      }
    };
  });

module.controller('crtl', function($scope) {})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="crtl">
  <test>text</test>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile the element.

```
var elm = angular.element(ng_select_str);
elm = $compile(elm)(scope);
$('#preview').append(elm);
```

Your directive should look something like this:

```
var module = angular.module('app', []);

module.directive('myWidget',
    ['$compile'
        function($compile) {
            return {
                restrict: 'AE',
                link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    var elm = angular.element(ng_select_str);
                    elm = $compile(elm)(scope);
                    $('#preview').append(elm);
                }
            };
        }
    ]);
```